# AttributeError thrown when running Python 3 unittest

Tags: python, linux, unit-testing, python-3.x

I am trying to run the following python command to bring up the unittest, but it failed on my Linux environment. However, same command worked fine on my Windows environment. Can't figure out what could be wrong. Any advice?
Note that "persistence" is a python package, and "PersistenceAcceptanceTest.py" is a python file under "persistence".

```
    $ /opt/python-3.4.3/bin/python3.4 -m unittest persistence.PersistenceAcceptanceTest -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/opt/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/unittest/__main__.py", line 18, in <module>
    main(module=None)
  File "/opt/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/unittest/main.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/opt/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/unittest/main.py", line 139, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/opt/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/unittest/main.py", line 146, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/opt/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 146, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/opt/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 146, in <listcomp>
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/opt/python-3.4.3/lib/python3.4/unittest/loader.py", line 114, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PersistenceAcceptanceTest'
```

Comment: what's the name of your .py file? if you use the same name as the module, it can cause an attribute error

Comment: "PersistenceAcceptanceTest.py" is the file name, which has (only) one class inheriting from "unittest.TestCase", and there is a line in this file as: if __name__ == '__main__':
  unittest.main()

Comment: There are underscore before and after "name" and "main".  They are not shown above.

Comment: I don't mean to doubt you, but are you sure that there is a 'persistenceAcceptenceTest.py' file that exists? It might be worth looking through the files in you python libraries

Comment: @NaiteJu you can use `\`__main__\`` in comments to add syntax highlighting (and not loosing your `__`.